# How to delete from set one specified Pointer*?

Tags: c++, stl

If I have `set<Pointer*>`, `Pointer*` is pointer to custom class, `set` is from the Standard Library. How to delete from set one specified `Pointer*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SGI's STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html):

```
size_type erase(const key_type& k)  Associative Container   Erases the element whose key is k.
```

Regardless of the fact that the `std::set` is containing pointers or any other types, this erases an element from the set. If your pointer is pointing to a dynamically allocated object/array, you must remember to `delete`/`delete[]` it after erasing it from the set (which shouldn't be a problem, since you already have the pointer)

Answer (score 3):

Use the set<>::erase function.  Here's some code I wrote to demonstrate:

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    int *a = new int(1);
    int *b = new int(2);

    std::set<int*> s;
    s.insert(a);
    s.insert(b);

    s.erase(b);

    assert(s.find(a) != s.end());
    assert(s.find(b) == s.end());

    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: `erase(b)` would be simpler than messing around with iterators.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right you are.  Updated.  (Also: doh!  That's what you get for reading only the first overload of a function)